# Antivirus in Mac

Tags: macos, mac, anti-virus

How can i know if an antivirus is installed on the system?

I can get all apps that are installed in the system, but i dont know get their categories.

Thanks for all.

Best regards!

Comment: Don't use Mac Anti Virus. Just. Don't. (unless you frequently share files with other PCs you might contaminate)

Answer (score 1):

If the Apps are installed from the Mac App Store, you can use a Finder Spotlight search and the 'Category' attribute.

Select **Other…** under the attribute dropdown menu and search for & check the attribute 'Category'.

[image: Search Attribute: Category]

Then do a search using that attribute.

[image: Searching Applications for Category: Utilities]

Antivirus apps from the Mac App Store are classed as 'Utilities'